# Why does Excel Grand Total returns error (#VALUE!) when getting data from SSAS OLAP Cube (MDX)?

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx

I am having a problem with Grand Total in Excel connected to a OLAP cube. I have a measure that are correctly calculated in row level, but returns error in Grand Total. Its returning me an error #VALUE! .

**EDIT:** *I have doing some experiences and verified that the error only appears when I have more then one year selected. If I have only one the data returns correct.*

I try several alterations to the measure with no success.

The origin measure:

```
IIF([Tipo de Stock].[Tipo de Stock].CurrentMember IS [Tipo de Stock].[Tipo de Stock].&[7] OR, NULL,
SUM({NULL:[Data].[Por Mês].PrevMember},[Measures].[Movimento Valor])
)
```

Some alterations trying to solve the problem:

```
IIF([Tipo de Stock].[Tipo de Stock].CurrentMember IS [Tipo de Stock].[Tipo de Stock].&[7] OR IsEmpty([Measures].[Movimento Valor]), NULL,
SUM({NULL:[Data].[Por Mês].PrevMember},[Measures].[Movimento Valor])
)

IIF([Tipo de Stock].[Tipo de Stock].CurrentMember IS [Tipo de Stock].[Tipo de Stock].&[7], NULL,
SUM({NULL:[Data].[Por Mês].PrevMember},IsEmpty([Measures].[Movimento Valor],0))
)

IIF([Tipo de Stock].[Tipo de Stock].CurrentMember IS [Tipo de Stock].[Tipo de Stock].&[7], NULL,
IsEmpty(SUM({NULL:[Data].[Por Mês].PrevMember},[Measures].[Movimento Valor]),0)
)
```

I have try also with CoalesceEmpty instead IsEmpty.

*Edit2 :I try to implement a SCOPE and it returns values in Grand Total, but the Values are the SUM of all rows. The idea is that the grand total has the first value.*

```
SCOPE([Measures].[Stock Inicial Valor]); 
    SCOPE([Data].[Por Mês].[Mês].members);  
        THIS = SUM({NULL:[Data].[Por Mês].PrevMember},[Measures].[Movimento Valor]); 
    END SCOPE;      
END SCOPE;
```

Any one can help get to the right track.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If the grand total is the total at the bottom, what is on rows? Is it the `Por Mês` attribute such that the grand total is the All member on that attribute?

Comment: Can you install this free Excel extension and run this feature to get an error message? https://olappivottableextensions.github.io/View-Error-Message.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
IIF(
  [Tipo de Stock].[Tipo de Stock].CurrentMember IS [Tipo de Stock].[Tipo de Stock].&[7] 
  OR [Data].[Por Mês].PrevMember IS NULL,
  NULL,
  SUM({NULL:[Data].[Por Mês].PrevMember},[Measures].[Movimento Valor])
)
```

I suspect the problem is that {Null:Null} isn’t allowed so we are protecting against that in the new IIF statement.

If that’s not the problem then please install this free Excel extension and use this [feature](https://olappivottableextensions.github.io/View-Error-Message.html) to get a proper error message to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Thanks Greg, 

I try your suggestion, but with no success. 

I try to implement a SCOPE and it returns values in Grand Total, but the Values are the SUM of all rows. The idea is that the grand total has the first value.

Comment: @RicardoCastro did you install that extension and capture an error behind the #VALUE! cell? Can you provide an updated screenshot showing what my calculation returned?

Comment: Hi @Greg,

First of all thank you very much for your help. However I am no longer getting the error using Scope as I put it in the edition above or the suggestion you gave me to add "[Date]. [Per Month] .PrevMember IS NULL", but Total returns the sum when the that I needed in Total was the value of the first member.

The idea is that this metric returns the initial stock per month and in total I wanted the value of the first month that is being viewed.